# How to debug GKE node pool nodes being re-created

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

GKE cloud logging and monitoring is not leading me to root cause. Over some period every single node was replaced (I could verify by their age with kubectl) leading to a short complete outage (several minutes) for all services as detected by external monitoring.

1. Nodes are not preemtible
2. `gcloud container operations list` does not show any node-upgrade operations
3. In cloud Logging Node event logs, there were multiple of these:
   `Node <...> status is now: NodeNotReady`
   `Deleting node <...> because it does not exist in the cloud provider`
   `Node <...> event: Removing Node <...> from Controller`
4. node-problem-detector logs has a bunch of these:

```
"2022/05/26 20:35:10 Failed to export to Stackdriver: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Deadline expired before operation could complete.: gce_instance{zone:europe-west2-a,instance_id:<...>} timeSeries[0-199]: kubernetes.io/internal/node/guest/net/rx_multicast{instance_name<...>,interface_namegkeb5dd8ca7306}"
```

5. Cluster autoscaler shows only a few nodes added and removed, but spread out over several hours.
6. During the period building up to this, one service in the cluster was receiving a DDoS attack, so network pressure was high, but there was no CPU throttling or OOM kills.